# Query between datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two DateTime columns, `_dateEntry` and `_dateUpdate`.

I've to create a query and choose the right datetime column based on these conditions: take the most recent between `_dateEntry` and `_dateUpdate`. `_dateUpdate` might be null, so I wrote this condition

```
SELECT id, description, ISNULL(_dateUpdate, _dateEntry) as date FROM mytable
```

but is not enought as I've to get also the most recent. How can I modify my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose _dateEntry is never NULL. If can be NULL tell me because I change my query

Try this:

```
SELECT id, description, 
CASE
   WHEN _dateUpdate IS NULL THEN _dateEntry
   WHEN _dateUpdate > _dateEntry THEN dateUpdate
   ELSE _dateEntry
END as date 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN _dateUpdate IS NULL THEN _dateEntry
   WHEN _dateUpdate > _dateEntry THEN dateUpdate
   ELSE _dateEntry
END desc
```

So if _dateUpdate  IS NULL you'll get the value of _dateEntry, so the order is on two fields

Answer (score 4):

You can use a case to return what you want:

```
SELECT
    id
    , description
    , CASE WHEN _dateEntry > ISNULL(_dateUpdate,0) 
           THEN _dateEntry ELSE _dateUpdate END AS date
FROM
    mytable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, description, MAX(ISNULL(_dateUpdate, _dateEntry)) AS date 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, description
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, description, ISNULL(_dateUpdate, _dateEntry) as date 
FROM mytable ORDER BY ISNULL(_dateUpdate, _dateEntry) desc
```